# Rails helper with HAML to take multiple arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Is there a way to get Rails helper to take multiple arguments from the view?

For example, I have a method below from `application_helper.rb` file but not sure of a way to pass in arguments?

```
def box
        haml_tag :div, :class => 'row' do
            haml_tag :div, :class => 'col-lg-6' do
                haml_tag :div, :class => 'box' do
                    haml_tag :header do
                        haml_tag :div, :class => 'icons' do
                            haml_tag :i, :class => 'fa fa-edit'
                        end
                        haml_tag :h5 do
                        end
                    end
                    haml_tag :div, :class => 'body' do
                        yield
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: `def box(arg1, arg2, ...)` ?

Comment: I get this error when I put more than one argument `wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`

Comment: when you define the method with 2 arguments, you have to call it with 2 arguments

Comment: Unless you want to use some default values...